# Why random number doesn't change in every iteration?

Tags: javascript

I want to set a matrix with random numbers.
I used a function to create a 0 matrix first, then loop through every cell and assign a random number to it.

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  let value = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  if (value === 0)
    return getRandomArbitrary(min, max);
  return value;
}

function matrix(m, n, d) {
  return Array.apply(null, new Array(m)).map(
    Array.prototype.valueOf,
    Array.apply(null, new Array(n)).map(
      function() {
        return d;
      }
    )
  );
}

let weight_1 = matrix(4, 3, 0);

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    weight_1[i][j] = getRandomArbitrary(-1, 1);
  }
}

console.table(weight_1)
```

When I run the code, I get the following output.[image]

As can be seen in the picture, the random value changes only when `i` changes. Is this related to JS being asynchronous or because random numbers generated by `Math.random` has a relation to timestamp?

Comment: There is no asynchronous stuff in the code posted.

Comment: @Pointy Do you have any idea why I am getting that result?

Comment: oh oh wait, I see the problem.

Comment: Do a `console.log(weight_1)`, which will give you a clue. The arrays in the "matrix" are references of the first one.

Comment: You've created a matrix of references. (@RickardElimää beat me to it ;)) You can simplify your matrix generation `return Array.from({ length: m }, (_, i) => Array(n).fill(d))` keep in mind that if `d` is an object the `fill` will populate the inner arrays with references to the same `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.valueOf` is `Object.prototype.valueOf`, and simply returns the receiver value (`this` argument). It does not create a copy of the array - so you are `map`ping to an outer array that contains the same inner array at every index. Instead, use

```
function matrix(m, n, d) {
  return Array.apply(null, new Array(m)).map(
    function() {
      return Array.apply(null, new Array(n)).map(
        function() {
          return d;
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

or the simpler and more conventionally formatted

```
function matrix(m, n, d) {
  return Array.from({length: m}, () =>
    Array.from({length: n}, () =>
      d
    )
  );
}
```

Also you might want to make `d`  a callback function and call it, so that you create your matrix directly by `matrix(4, 3, () => getRandomArbitrary(-1, 1))` instead of initialising it with `0` and then looping it to change the values.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue but there is one thing that I didn't understand. After creating the "matrix" I am overwriting each value, Isn't this suppose to fix problem caused by `map` function?

Comment: @kenarsuleyman No, every row of the matrix is the *same* row. Writing a cell in "one of the rows" writes that column in "all rows". To fix the problem, and create individual rows, you'd have needed to do `weight_1[i] = []`

Comment: Ahhhh, now I understood. Thanks.